# Макрос TASM выдаёт warning

Tags: ассемблер, макросы, макрос, tasm

Написал вот такой макрос:

```
__defdef macro const,value
  ifndef const
    const = value
  endif
endm
```

Макрос определяет константу, если она не была определена ранее.
Однако есть проблема: компилер выдаёт warning, что "Module is pass depending". Как от этого избавиться?

И ещё, можно ли как-то определить: используется ли та или иная процедура в коде или нет? Чтобы написать include с несколькими процедурами, а в код включать только те, которые реально используются.

И как проверить - какой ассемблер используется: TASM, MASM или FASM ?
Может, какие-то символы определены для этого?

Answer (score 1):

> компилер выдаёт warning, что "Module is pass depending"

А дальше идёт что-то вроде "compatibility pass was done"? Это предупреждение о том, что в данном случае для правильной сборки нужно делать два прохода. Но по умолчанию делается один, вот он и предупреждает что вынужден сделать второй круг. Лечится ключом командной строки `/M2`

> можно ли как-то определить: используется ли та или иная процедура в коде или нет?

Никак. Вообще это не самая лучшая практика - подключать процедуры директивами `INCLUDE`. Раздельная компиляция и выборочная линковка куда эффективней.

> И как проверить - какой ассемблер используется: TASM, MASM или FASM ?

В NASM есть `__NASM_VER__`, `__NASM_VERSION_ID__` и т.д. В MASM, ЕМНИП,  макро `@Version`. Может и в других что есть, надо в документации копаться. Но гиблое это дело, писать сразу под несколько ассемблеров...

Comment: Да, дальше идёт "compatibility pass was done". Но /m2 не помогает (там и так стоит ключ /m, замена его на /m2 ничего не меняет, но если убрать /m или /m2, warning'ов появляется больше)

Comment: @JinX, приведите минимальный, но полноценный пример, который можно собрать и посмотреть на вывод.

Comment: Сделать минимальный не получается, поэтому приведу то, что есть...
https://cloud.mail.ru/public/4fy5/sNjiiZKJh